# Autocomplete de jQuery no sugiere resultados

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy asignando la función "autocomplete" de jQuery a un input pero éste no muestra los resultados.

Los datos se recogen de la BD a través de una función PHP mediante método post. Recorriendo la traza he comprobado que los datos se reciben, se convierten en un array de strings y se pasan a una variable, la cual es llamada en el source de la función autocomplete.

Os paso el código de jQuery:

```
$.post("../../events_front_end/autocomplete_events/",{'autocomplete':true},function(data,status){
//console.log(data);
var json=JSON.parse(data);
var name_events=json.band_name;

//AQUI ENTRA
console.log(name_events);

var suggestions =new Array();

for (var i =0; i<name_events.length; i++){
  suggestions.push(name_events[i].band_name);
}//end of for

//AQUI ENTRA
console.log(suggestions);

$("#keyword").autocomplete({
  source: suggestions,
  minLength:1,
  select:function(event, ui){
    //AQUI NO ENTRA
    console.log("Estoy en select");
    var keyword =ui.item.label;
    count_event(keyword);
  }
});
}).fail(function(xhr){
  $("#results").load("../../events_front_end/view_error_false/",{'view_error':false});
  $('.pagination').html('');
reset();
});//End of $.post autocomplete
```

Alguien podría orientarme sobre dónde puede estar el error? He realizado varias pruebas sin éxito. Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero hay que revisar que obtengas resultados.

Comment: @Cig Como podrás observar en el código, existen varios console.log() que muestran por consola los resultados de la base de datos. Se muestran cuando se hace el parse desde el JSON y cuando se introducen en el array de strings.

Comment: tienes lo que te arroja el log suggestions?

Comment: Si lo acabo de añadir, Es un array de strings.

Comment: Tienes montado el archivo donde consultas el post? al parecer todo funciona bien...

Comment: @Cig. Si, donde consulto el post es un controlador de php. Ahí me entra y me devuelve la consulta con el JSON al que le hago el parse. Lo único que veo diferente son las librerías que has utilizado. Voy a probar con esas a ver.

Comment: Como ya habia comprobado, no es problema de librerías.

Comment: Como puedes ver en mi respuesta, yo quito dentro de tu petición ajax el control de autocomplete, y creo el array suggestion de manera global para que pueda ser utilizado en otras funciones, en este caso el autocomplete, pero como no se de donde obtienes los datos, no puedo crearte un ejemplo mas acertado que el que te puse.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />

var suggestions =new Array();
$.post("../../events_front_end/autocomplete_events/",
          {
            'autocomplete':true
          },
          function(data,status){
          var json=JSON.parse(data);
          var name_events=json.band_name;

         //AQUI ENTRA
         console.log(name_events);

         for (var i =0; i<name_events.length; i++)
             {
               suggestions.push(name_events[i].band_name);
             }//end of for    
         }).fail(function(xhr){
               $("#results").load("../../events_front_end/view_error_false/",                         {'view_error':false});
               $('.pagination').html('');
               reset();
    });//End of $.post autocomplete

$("#keyword").autocomplete({
  source: suggestions,
  minLength:1,
  select:function(event, ui){
    //AQUI NO ENTRA
    console.log("Estoy en select");
    var keyword =ui.item.label;
    count_event(keyword);
  }
});
```